# Does showing that the difference of two sets is empty imply that they are equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In general, is it true that if $$A-B = \emptyset$$ then $$A=B$$

I can't think of how to prove this at the moment.

Comment: Let $A = \{0\}$ and $B = \{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.   You need the *symmetric difference* to be empty for that.   You are only part way there.

The set difference is just every element in the first set that is not also in the second set.

$$A-B ~=~ A\cap B^\complement ~=~ \{x: x\in A\wedge x\notin B\}$$

This being empty merely implies that the first set has no members outside the second.   That is, it is a subset. $$A-B=\emptyset ~\iff~ A\subseteq B$$

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Taking the difference of two sets $A - B$ does not require the second set ($B$) to be contained in the first ($A$); in just means to take everything in $A$ and not in $B$.

The statement "$A - B = \varnothing$" is equivalent to "$A \subseteq B$", but we don't necessarily have equality.